# PHP Oracle substraction from current row with previous row

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have data like below:

```
Time      | Count
17:31:49
17:35:52
17:36:54
17:38:12
17:39:12
17:40:12
17:41:57
17:43:47
17:45:27
17:48:12
17:48:17
```

Now I need to subtraction current row with previous row.

So this will be like this:

```
Time      | Count
17:31:49    formula: 17:35:52 - 17:31:49 = 04:03
17:35:52    formula: 17:36:54 - 17:35:52 = 01:02
17:36:54    formula: 17:38:12 - 17:36:54 = 01:58
17:38:12    and so on
17:39:12
17:40:12
17:41:57
17:43:47
17:45:27
17:48:12
17:48:17
```

Is it possible to do the calculation only using query or need PHP (I'm using this) to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can use `lead()`:

```
select time, lead(time) over(order by time) - time diff
from mytable
```

It is unclear what the datatype of `time` is. If it is a `DATE`, then you can substract, and you get a decimal number representing the difference in days; you can format or use arithmetics to get the results you desire.

If it is of some other datatype (a string?), then you need to build your own logic to handle the substraction.